# Swift protocol with constrained associated type error "Type is not convertible"

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift2, associated-types

I have created 2 protocols with associated types. A type conforming to `Reader` should be able to produce an instance of a type conforming to `Value`.

The layer of complexity comes from a type conforming to `Manager` should be able to produce a concrete `Reader` instance which produces a specific type of `Value` (either `Value1` or `Value2`).

With my concrete implementation of `Manager1` I'd like it to always produce `Reader1` which in turn produces instances of `Value1`.

Could someone explain why

> "Reader1 is not convertible to ManagedReaderType?"

When the erroneous line is changed to (for now) return `nil` it all compiles just fine but now I can't instantiate either `Reader1` or `Reader2`.

The following can be pasted into a Playground to see the error:

```
import Foundation

protocol Value {
    var value: Int { get }
}

protocol Reader {
    typealias ReaderValueType: Value
    func value() -> ReaderValueType
}

protocol Manager {
    typealias ManagerValueType: Value

    func read<ManagerReaderType: Reader where ManagerReaderType.ReaderValueType == ManagerValueType>() -> ManagerReaderType?
}

struct Value1: Value {
    let value: Int = 1
}

struct Value2: Value {
    let value: Int = 2
}

struct Reader1: Reader {
    func value() -> Value1 {
        return Value1()
    }
}

struct Reader2: Reader {
    func value() -> Value2 {
        return Value2()
    }
}

class Manager1: Manager {
    typealias ManagerValueType = Value1

    let v = ManagerValueType()
    func read<ManagerReaderType: Reader where ManagerReaderType.ReaderValueType == ManagerValueType>() -> ManagerReaderType? {
        return Reader1()// Error: "Reader1 is not convertible to ManagedReaderType?" Try swapping to return nil which does compile.
    }
}

let manager = Manager1()
let v = manager.v.value
let a: Reader1? = manager.read()
a.dynamicType
```

Comment: typealias ManagerValueType: Value is wrong - you define typealias'es with "=", like typealias ManagerValueType = Value

Comment: `typealias ManagerValueType: Value` within the protocol `Manager` is a constraint, *not* setting the type.

Comment: Is this code only a short example of a bigger project or is it your curiosity how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's a short example of a bigger project while also trying to explore the features of Swift. I'll accept an answer that is an alternative approach to something like this or an explanation as to why the above does not work and potential solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because `ManagerReaderType` in the `read` function is only a generic placeholder for any type which conforms to `Reader` and its `ReaderValueType` is equal to the one of `ManagerReaderType`. So the actual type of `ManagerReaderType` is not determined by the function itself, instead the type of the variable which gets assigned declares the type:

```
let manager = Manager1()
let reader1: Reader1? = manager.read() // ManagerReaderType is of type Reader1
let reader2: Reader2? = manager.read() // ManagerReaderType is of type Reader2
```

if you return `nil` it can be converted to any optional type so it always works.

As an alternative you can return a specific type of type `Reader`:

```
protocol Manager {
    // this is similar to the Generator of a SequenceType which has the Element type
    // but it constraints the ManagerReaderType to one specific Reader
    typealias ManagerReaderType: Reader

    func read() -> ManagerReaderType?
}

class Manager1: Manager {

    func read() -> Reader1? {
        return Reader1()
    }
}
```

This is the best approach with protocols due to the lack of "true" generics (the following isn't supported (yet)):

```
// this would perfectly match your requirements
protocol Reader<T: Value> {
    fun value() -> T
}

protocol Manager<T: Value> {
    func read() -> Reader<T>?
}

class Manager1: Manager<Value1> {
    func read() -> Reader<Value1>? {
        return Reader1()
    }
}
```

So the best workaround would be to make `Reader` a generic class and `Reader1` and `Reader2` subclass a specific generic type of it:

```
class Reader<T: Value> {
    func value() -> T {
        // or provide a dummy value
        fatalError("implement me")
    }
}

// a small change in the function signature
protocol Manager {
    typealias ManagerValueType: Value
    func read() -> Reader<ManagerValueType>?
}

class Reader1: Reader<Value1> {
    override func value() -> Value1 {
        return Value1()
    }
}

class Reader2: Reader<Value2> {
    override func value() -> Value2 {
        return Value2()
    }
}

class Manager1: Manager {
    typealias ManagerValueType = Value1

    func read() -> Reader<ManagerValueType>? {
        return Reader1()
    }
}

let manager = Manager1()

// you have to cast it, otherwise it is of type Reader<Value1>
let a: Reader1? = manager.read() as! Reader1?
```

This implementation should solve you problem, but the `Readers` are now reference types and a copy function should be considered.