# Adding constraint to protocol's `associatedtype`

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

Considering the following code :

```
protocol __Strideable {
    associatedtype Stride
}

struct __ClosedRangeIndex<Bound: __Strideable> where Bound.Stride: SignedInteger {
}

protocol __ClosedRangeType {
    associatedtype Bound: __Strideable

    // Error: Type 'Self._Bound.Stride' does not conform to protocol 'SignedInteger'
    var startIndex: __ClosedRangeIndex<Bound> { get }
}
```

Is it possible to add a constraint to the `associatedtype` ?

Something like :
`associatedtype _Bound: __Strideable where _Bound.String: SignedInteger` ? (that one doesn't work obviously)

Comment: Move the startIndex declaration to a protocol extension with a where clause.

Comment: @Sealos I can't because I don't want to implement `startIndex` myself, I'm planning to extend some Swift internal structure which already have that property (i.e `extension CountableClosedRange: __ClosedRangeType {}`)

Comment: I see. I believe associated types can also restrict the type allowed, check this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766454/swift-protocol-with-constrained-associated-type-error-type-is-not-convertible

Comment: @Sealos I also found it but it didn't help unfortunatly. FYI, a proposal that treat the subject is currently in review https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md

Comment: Ohh, I see, well, at least they are evaluating it! Thanks for the link.